# How to /as sysdba to db running on Docker?

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose, privileges

I have an Oracle database that is running on Docker and a password from my user is going to be expired.

I tried `alter profile <profile_name> limit password_life_time UNLIMITED;` but got `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`

AFAIK, in order to succesfully execute `alter profile <profile_name> limit password_life_time UNLIMITED;` I have to log in `/as sysdba`

Could you please give me a hint how can I workaround it in my case? Is it possible to connect `/as sysdba` in my case?

Answer (score 2):

Just update their password.

ALTER USER EXPIRING_SOON IDENTIFIED BY NEW_PASSWORD;

This will reset the expiration window for the user.

To login as SYS w/o a password, open a terminal for your docker container, and run SQL*Plus from there.